# How to track screen on firebase analytics flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to add a firebase analytics track screen to my app.
I tried to enter it in the menu like in the picture below but it always doesn't read

[image: menu for tracking screen]

I've tried some code but it doesn't work. For now, the code I'm using is as follows:

```
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

 onGenerateRoute: widget.appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
          builder: EasyLoading.init(),
          initialRoute: splashScreenRoute,
          navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[
            // FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: _analytics),
            observer
          ]
```

and on each screen I add code like this below on each initState()

```
analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: 'Page Detail Mobil');
```

i have re-run the app but it doesn't work track screen and put in firebase analytic. please help me thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used different function to track my screens. I have called my logScreens function on routing or you can call it on initState of each pages.

This is my analytic_service.dart

```
class AnalyticsService {
 final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

  Future logScreens({@required String? name}) async {
  await _analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: name);
 }
}
```

and this is locator.dart

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

import 'analytic_service.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  if (!locator.isRegistered<AnalyticsService>()) {
    locator.registerLazySingleton(() => AnalyticsService());
  }
}
```

Call the logScreens function when needed.

```
locator<AnalyticsService>().logScreens(name: "Dashboard");
```

And this will be logged in analytics like this.

[image]

Try this on DebugView. Click on the screen_view. It will show the screen like this.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will go first

Comment: After I install it, does it take time for analytics to bring up the logs?

Comment: Yes usually it take 24 hrs to get data in dashboard. 1st check it on debugview to see if it logs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: oke thankyou, can i ask one more question? in analytics_service.dart does it need to be added
`class AnalyticsService {
 Future logScreens({@required String? name}) async {
  await _analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: name);
 }
}`
so that it can be called in class locator.dart?

Comment: Oops sorry. I missed that. Yes obviously. I have edited my code. Thanks

Comment: If it helps you please do an upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: okay if it work i wiil do that. thankyou

Comment: hai @Fahmida I have tried the code that you have sent. then i was doing a debugview on firebase analytics. but when entering the pages to be tracked, the debug view only shows screen_view. and does not display the actual page name

Comment: Hey I have edited my answer. Check it

Comment: thankyou it works!!

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was something else. The issue with `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` for me was that the `defaultRouteFilter` only does a check if the generated item is a `PageRoute`. Since i returned something else the `routeFilter` failed and it never tracked the screen name correctly. So all I had to change was:

```
navigatorObservers: [
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(
        analytics: analytics,
        routeFilter: (_) => true,  // Or put your own custom check here
    ),
]
```

Furthermore the screen tracking events did show up almost immediately with the Firebase real-time dashboard.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thank you man! i tried almost everything but now i got it working!

Comment: this worked if you only have a `home:` page without complex routes, and all other stateless widgets / screens opened from there... thanks!